# Enabling like button comment field for secure browsing users

Tags: ssl, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-comments

We've been having trouble with inconsistent display of the like button comment field on our external sites (i.e. some people see it pop up after clicking the like button, and some people don't). We searched around and made sure that the app id referenced when loading the HTML5 version of the like button code matched the website domain in the app settings ([per this thread](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2688836/facebook-like-button-xfbml-comment-not-working)), and finally determined that the "problem" is the user's security settings: if they have enabled "secure browsing" in their security settings, then they won't see the comment field pop up unless the page is also hosted securely. (only other place I could find this discussed is [on this site](http://adigitalnotepad.com/post/facebook-like-button-and-undocumented-https-requirement))

Has anyone figured out a workaround for this? It appears that the iframe version doesn't have this problem (though it does make the user click a link to see the comment field), but it requires 400px of minimum width which busts our layouts. We want to always make the comment field appears after the user clicks the like button, but it isn't feasible for us to host every page on the site securely. Any suggestions?